# How to fix a tcltk error on R CMD check for macos

Tags: r, github-actions, cran, tcltk

I'm getting the following error on a [Github Action R CMD check for Mac OS](https://github.com/robjhyndman/weird-package/actions/runs/7525096918/job/20480908005). Other OSs give no errors. Strangely, my package does not use tcltk at all. I can't figure out how to fix the package to avoid the problem, and CRAN won't let me upload with this problem.

```bash
── Install failure ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

* installing *source* package ‘weird’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
tcltk DLL is linked to '/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib'
Error: Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from www.xquartz.org
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘weird’
* removing ‘/Users/runner/work/weird-package/weird-package/check/weird.Rcheck/weird’

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I know I can fix the problem on Github Action by adding

```yaml
- name: Install XQuartz on macOS
  if: runner.os == 'macOS'
  run: brew install xquartz --cask
```

to the yaml, but that only avoids the problem on Github. The problem is still there when I submit to CRAN.

Comment: I would try and remove each of your dependencies (one by one) to see which one introduces the tcltk dependency. You could also try adding tcltk to `Suggests`.

Comment: I've already tried adding tcltk to `Suggests` and it made no difference. Yes, removing dependencies may help to identify the tcltk dependency, but it won't solve the problem unless I can find an alternative way to implement the method the dependency handles.

Comment: Yes, but if you know exactly how the tcltk dependency is introduced, you might be able to find a solution. After all, packages with that dependency are on CRAN (but usually they have `SystemRequirements:  Tcl/Tk (>= 8.6)`).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, in case anyone has the same problem.

It turns out that the CRAN macos machine was missing the Tcl/Tk libraries and any package needing them was causing errors. So the problem was CRAN's, not mine.

The GitHub Actions fix is simply to add `xquartz` to the yaml:

```yaml
- name: Install XQuartz on macOS
  if: runner.os == 'macOS'
  run: brew install xquartz --cask
```